# SQL Server Using Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

After a Select Query I have the following table:

```
id  CN    SN    DC
1   null  null  null
1   1234  null  1245
1   null  2536  null
2   null  null  null
2   null  2596  null
```

I want make using select command in SQL SERVER something like:

```
id   CN    SN    DC
1    1234  2536  1245
2    null  2596  null
```

Can anyone help me with that, please?
Thank you!

Comment: What are the rules that would produce this result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want the maximum value returned for each column:

```
select id, max(CN) as CN, max(SN) as SN, max(DC) as DC
from MyTable
group by id
```

Comment: @satish The maximum value in the column for that `id`. So for id=1, it returns 2536, for id=2 it returns 2596.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i'm getting this right, but you want to add everything under id 1 together (columns) and the same for id 2?

```
Select id, SUM(ISNULL(CN, 0)), SUM(ISNULL(SN, 0)), SUM(ISNULL(DC, 0)) FROM table
Group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling what to do when more than one 'CN', 'SN' or 'DC' exists on one id, so there are many solutions to your problem, for example;

```
SELECT id, SUM(CN) CN, SUM(SN) SN, SUM(DC) DC
FROM Table1
GROUP BY id;
```

and

```
SELECT id, MAX(CN) CN, MAX(SN) SN, MAX(DC) DC
FROM Table1
GROUP BY id;
```

are equally correct.

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65a18/3).

Answer (score -1):

You are using a FULL OUTER JOIN, right?

Probably you want just to use the LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: So can you show the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` syntax that would yield the desired result?

Comment: Forget it... the correct answer is using the "group by" with the max aggregation function